# passing mixed string and int parameters to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, parameters

I've had a look around and can't seem to find a working solution, so here's the requirements.

I'm building a system that takes data from a master page and loads it into a modal style window for quick data processing. I have a javascript function passing 4 status parameters, and whilst 3 of them will always be integers, one of them can be integer or string.

The function works if all 4 parameters are integer, but fails when a string is passed.

```
function passJob(jobid,equipid,status,location) {

var a = document.getElementById('jobnumber');
var b = document.getElementById('equipid');
var c = document.getElementById('status');
var d = document.getElementById('location');
  a.value = jobid;
  b.value = equipid;  
  c.value = status;  
  d.value = location;  
}
```

PHP

```
<a href='#' onclick='passJob($sr,$eid,$ss,$sl);'>Modify Job</a>
```

$sr, $ss and $sl will always be numeric, $eid will either be integer, or a string starting with M and then having a number after it.

I've tried adding quotes to the variables, around the variables, inside the function etc and no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass as string if you do not know what they are - also make sure you do not nest the same type of quote:

```
onclick='passJob($sr,"$eid",$ss,$sl);'
```

Comment: I've used this solution. Initially I was echoing the values into the function via php, whilst enclosed the ' character was coming through as an unexpected token. I've changed the programming style of that section of the page to allow echoing inside quote marks !

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in quotes. This treats it like a string at all times to avoid any potential JavaScript parsing errors.

```
<a href="#" onclick="passJob($sr, '$eid', $ss, $sl);">Modify Job</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you do not properly encode the variables in a Javascript notation. Try:

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='passJob(".json_encode($sr).",".json_encode($eid).",".json_encode($ss).",".json_encode($sl).");'>Modify Job</a>";
```

Comment: No idea why this got down-voted. JSON encoding the variable is the most reliable way to pass it to JavaScript without needing to know what the variable actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Do like below

```
<a href="#" onclick="passJob($sr, '$eid', $ss, $sl);">Modify Job</a>
```